# xcode filter NSMutableArray elements by string contents

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I would like to filter NSMutableArray elements that contains "some" string. ListArchives is filled with string elements and listFiles must be a filtered one. XCode generates an alert at last posted line. What am doing wrong? any other method to filter elements of NSMutableArray?

```
NSString *match = @"*some*"; 
listFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like[cd] %@", match];

listFiles = [listArchives filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sPredicate];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `contains` instead of `like`, for example as follows:

```
NSString *match = @"some"; 
listFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", match];

listFiles = [[listArchives filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sPredicate] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: ok, seems better option. However still showing an alert, "Incomptaible pointer types assigning to NSMutableArray _strong from NSArray". So if I declare listFiles as NSArray solves it but no other way to get listFiles also mutable?

Comment: @Jaume This is because the filtered array is not known to the compiler to be an `NSMutableArray`. Try this instead of the last line: `[listFiles setArray:[listArchives filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sPredicate]];`

Comment: last line 
`listFiles = [[listArchives filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sPredicate] mutableCopy]`

Comment: @Nazir Thanks! You can always suggest an edit - it's often faster than writing a comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search as 'like' operator.
Lets say you have a NSArray with following contents :

```
static int count = 0;
NSArray *results = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"What was", @"What is", @"What will", nil];

NSString *targetString = @"What"
for (NSString *strObj in results)
{
    if ([strObj rangeOfString:targetString].location != NSNotFound){
        NSLog (@"Found: %@", strObj);
        count = count + 1;              
    }
}
NSLog(@"There were %d occurence of %@ string",count,targetString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *match = @"some";
listFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[c] %@", match];
listFiles = [listArchives filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sPredicate];
```

For robust searching this can serve you as some what "Like" serve in `SQL`.